# What is a diference between ((int) a) and (int(a))?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

What is a difference between `((int) a)` and `(int(a))`?

Is the second expression valid in pure "С" (not "C" under "C++")?

Comment: See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048921/different-meanings-of-parentheses-in-c

Comment: A good start when checking if something is valid in "pure C" is to compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` (or your compiler's equivalent). It will give you a correct answer 99% of the time.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, could you give an example of 1%, please?

Comment: @Evg - Not off the top of my head. But compilers do still have conformance bugs at times, hence my 1% error margin.

Comment: by "pure C" you mean "C" ?

Comment: @M.M The word is used to contrast it with "polluted C", AKA C++.

Comment: @M.M I mean "C"-program compiled with "C"-compiler and not "C" under "CPP"-compiler. ;)

Comment: If you're using C++, consider using modern c++ conversions:   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions

static_cast converts one type to another related type
dynamic_cast converts within inheritance hierarchies
const_cast adds or removes cv qualifiers
reinterpret_cast converts type to unrelated type

Comment: Rather than add a comment to each of the two correct answers, I'll just mention here that `int(a)` is a **function-style cast**. It was added to C++ in order to be able to invoke constructors to create temporary objects. When a class type has  a constructor that takes multiple arguments you can create a temporary object with `my_type(arg1, arg2)` or whatever. The function-style cast is just a simpler context for the same thing.

Comment: there's no such thing as `"C" under "C++"`. C and C++ are very different languages and when compiling C code even a C++ compiler must follow C rules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ cast syntax styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(type_name)identifier` (or more specifically [`(type_name)cast_expression` (6.5.4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4)) is a C-style cast. `(int(a))` is syntactically invalid in C unless `a` is a type. Then it could be part of a cast to a function taking type `a` and returning `int`, which would be a syntactically valid but semantically invalid cast, so useless too. `int(a);` in C would be a declaration equivalent to `int a;`.

C++ does support the `int(a)` syntax for casts (the type name must be a single word; it doesn't work with e.g., `unsigned long(a)`) on the grounds that `int` (the type name) then becomes kind of like a type with a parametrized constructor (although even this is in C++ grouped together with C-style casts as a kind of a deprecated way of casting, and the more fine-grained/visible `static_cast/reinterpret_cast/const_cast` casts are preferred).

The C++ syntax then appears to be quite interesting because this works (C++):

```
typedef int type_name;
type_name (a); //a declaration
a=0;
printf("%d\n", type_name(a)); //type_name(a) is a cast expr here
```

Comment: wouldn't int(a) be a an anonymous int object with a as parameter for the constructor, exactly the same way string("abc") is an anonymous string constructed with char* "abc" argument) ?

Comment: @Christophe Yes, that does makes a bit more sense overall.

Answer (score 7):

There's no difference between them in C++. However, C supports only the first cast operation.

See this example from [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/):

```
double x = 10.3;
int y;
y = (int) x;    // c-like cast notation 
y = int (x);    // functional notation
```